# In C,is casting to (void*) not needed/inadvisable for memcpy() just as it is not needed for malloc()?

Tags: c, casting, malloc, void-pointers, memcpy

I have some confusions about what I read from the following site about `memcpy()`(and `malloc()`):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

In that page,the following 2 lines are clearly stated:

**destination**

`Pointer to the destination array where the content is to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type void*.`

**source**

`Pointer to the source of data to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type const void*.`

But immediately after that,in the code,there is no casting to `void*` in the following two lines where `memcpy()` is used:

```
    memcpy ( person.name, myname, strlen(myname)+1 );
    memcpy ( &person_copy, &person, sizeof(person) );
```

Please answer the following 2 questions arising from this premise:

**1)** In C's case(as opposed to C++) is it all right and **advisable** not to cast to `void*` the return type or the arguments in `memcpy()` just as it is all right and **advisable** not to cast to `void*` the return type of `malloc()` in C?If so,as I intuitively feel, why is it explicitly stated in that reputed site that we **need to** cast it to `void*` (even though it doesn't use that in the code).Is that site wrong about it?

**2)** Now the real contradiction about that reputed site.Consider the following

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

In the case of `malloc()` ,in the description, it is written as if it is `optional` to cast to `void*` the return type (exact words "..`can be cast to the desired type`.."),unlike in the case of `memcpy()` above where it is said that it **is to be cast** into `void*`.But while in `memcpy()` the casting is not done even though it is written that `it is to be cast`,in the case of `malloc()`,the casting to `void*` is done even though it's written it `can be cast to void*`.Now I see something wrong in this as for **C** we are not supposed to cast `malloc()`'s return to `void*`.

To put the discrepancies in a nutshell again lest the people answering get confused in my wordy description:

--Is it advisable in C not to cast to `void*` the return and arguments of `memcpy()`?

--Is that site wrong about `malloc()` as it casts `malloc()` return to `void*` in C code.

Comment: `malloc` and `memcpy` only have marginal existence in C++, it is there mainly for compatibility with C. C++ has different constructs that better fit into their type system. So better don't take a C++ site as reference for C. It is just different.

Comment: @JensGustedt That crossed my mind once, but when I saw that the program itself is in C,I thought it was talking about C's case

Comment: @JensGustedt All programs in the `C standard library` section there are in C.

Comment: You can see from the function signature of `memcpy` that they provide that this is not a C site. The signature in C is different, it has `restrict`, which doesn't exist in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ISO/IEC 9899:2011 of C language specification, section 6.3.2.3, page 55:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

So you basically never need to cast the result of a `void*` to the desired type, neither you need to do the opposite.

Comment: I didn't quite get it.Can you explain it in the context of my question in a little more detail please.Your answer is like `all meat,but tough to chew`.Can you make it a little less dense,with details please?

Comment: Like why is cast is done for `malloc()` but not for `memcpy()` even though it's stated that it **is to be cast** for `memcpy()` but optional for `malloc()`?

Comment: There are no details. in C a void* can be converted to and from any other pointer odany different type without the need of a cast, sic et simpliciter. Forget what is written on that specific site, a cast is synctactically correct in both your cases but unnecessary.

Comment: Cast is correct for `malloc()`?But I have read many times on SO that using a cast for `malloc()` in C is bad as it hides errors!!

Comment: I said that it's synctactically correct, not that it is a good practice.

Comment: And one more thing.I have a notion that that site is very respected and is on top of google searches.But I have second thoughts about it as it uses a cast for `malloc()`.Should I approach that site's information with a pinch of salt henceforth?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture That site is quite *dis*respected among reputable C programmers. Stay away from it. Google "opengroup memset", "opengroup strcpy", "opengroup qsort", etc... because opengroup has a better set of references. ps. The code in your profile has aspects of undefined behaviour. Don't use xor swaps, especially on signed integers.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture that site is a _C++_ reference. Note that C++ is a difference language from C, and has different rules.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I discovered a new thing today thanks to you,but still confused about it.Since it was already getting long in comments,I will be posting it in a question in few minutes.Composing it right now.Do answer that when I post it.

Answer (score 1):

->for first question

memcpy, the cast is not required in C. It would be in C++.

->for second question

malloc returns a void pointer (void *), which indicates that it is a pointer to a region of unknown data type. The use of casting is required in C++ due to the strong type system, whereas this is not the case in C. The lack of a specific pointer type returned from malloc is type-unsafe behaviour according to some programmers: malloc allocates based on byte count but not on type. This is different from the C++ new operator that returns a pointer whose type relies on the operand

Answer (score 1):

In C we directly assign void* to any type and vice-versa, we don't have to explicitly typecast.

```
int   *i_ptr = (int *)0xABCD;   //some address
printf("address :%p\n",i_ptr);
void  *v_ptr = i_ptr;           //no need to explictly typecast
printf("address :%p\n",v_ptr);
float *f_ptr = v_ptr;           //this will throw error in cpp
printf("address :%p\n",f_ptr);
```

output:

```
address :0xabcd
address :0xabcd
address :0xabcd
```

All these are valid statements in C, but in CPP **float *f_ptr = v_ptr** will cause error **invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’**.